# How can I run the same scripts in three different environments

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, grid

Here is my script:

```
public class VerifyPageContent {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\Selenium Drivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

        ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports("C:/SeleniumDataAndScripts/Reports/qa/new.html", true);

        ExtentTest test = extent.startTest("Verify Page Content");

        extent.addSystemInfo("Environment" , "QA");


        //Opening Website and Capturing Screenshot

        driver.get("http://ww3.nedbank.co.za");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();



        //QA
                                            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////        
                                            ///VERIFY WEBSITE HEADER CONTENTS               ///
                                            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////     


        //NEDBANK LOGO  

        test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Verifying 'Nedbank Logo' element");

           String expTextLogo = "Nedbank"; 

          String actTextLogo = driver.findElement(By.id("main-header")).getText();

            if(actTextLogo.contains(expTextLogo)){

                test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Expected element '"+expTextLogo+"' is Present in the web page");
                System.out.println("0) Expected element '"+expTextLogo+"' is present in the web page.");
            }else{

                test.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Expected element '"+expTextLogo+"' is not present in the web page");
                System.out.println("0) Expected element '"+expTextLogo+"' is not present in the web page.");

            }   

            extent.endTest(test);
            extent.flush();


        //APPLY ONLINE                       


        test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Verifying Apply online element");

       String expText = "Apply online"; 

      String actText = driver.findElement(By.id("main-header")).getText();

        if(actText.contains(expText)){

            test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Expected element '"+expText+"' is Present in the web page");
            System.out.println("1) Expected element '"+expText+"' is present in the web page.");
        }else{

            test.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Expected element '"+expText+"' is not present in the web page");
            System.out.println("1) Expected element '"+expText+"' is not present in the web page.");

        }   

        extent.endTest(test);
        extent.flush();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the general description of what you should do:

1. Set up **SeleniumGrid** hub
2. Set up nodes within different environments you would like to run your tests
3. Isolate your test code within a separate method (**of course it is better to use test frameworks like JUnit or TestNG**). Your test method should take `WebDriver` as a parameter because you will have to re-instantiate drivers for different environments.
4. Where you will call your test code you need to loop through your environment configurations which you will define via `DesiredCapabilities` class, create a `RemoteWebDriver` with those capabilities and call your test method sending your new `WebDriver` there.

This is basically how you will achieve running one test against several different environments.

So the code would look approximately like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

    List<Environment> envs = new ArrayList<>();
    envs.add(new Environment(Platform.LINUX, BrowserType.CHROME));
    envs.add(new Environment(Platform.WINDOWS, BrowserType.CHROME));
    envs.add(new Environment(Platform.WINDOWS, BrowserType.EDGE));


    for(Environment env: envs){
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setBrowserName(env.getBrowserType());
        caps.setPlatform(env.getPlatform());
        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("YOUR_URL"), caps);
        try{
            driver.get("http://ww3.nedbank.co.za");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            test(driver);
        }finally {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

}
```

Where *YOUR_URL* is the URL of your SeleniumGrid hub and `test(driver)` is a method where you put all your test code. This code also uses one custom class that is defined as shown below:

```
public class Environment {

    Platform platform;
    String browserType;

    public Environment(Platform platform, String browserType) {
        this.platform = platform;
        this.browserType = browserType;
    }

    public Platform getPlatform() {
        return platform;
    }

    public String getBrowserType() {
        return browserType;
    }
}
```

This approach lets you add new environments or remove ones that are not required any more.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple options to run the same scripts in different environments.

- By using the [selenium grid](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp). Runs your tests across different environments parallel.
- You can also try running the selenium on top of a [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) which will helps to run the script in different environments virtually. Try this [link](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/configure-selenium-grid-using-docker). After that in your script add the following line for executing in parallel.

> driver = new RemoteWebDriver (new
>   URL(“http://youripaddress:portnumber/wd/hub”), capabilities);